# Using Mosquitto MQTT certs with ActiveMQ

Tags: java, ssl, activemq-classic, keystore, mosquitto

So I can follow the steps here 
[Securing Apache ActiveMQ - How do I use SSL](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl.html)

to secure ActiveMQ and generate the required keystores/truststore for a JAVA client to connect sucessfully.

I can also secure Mosquitto following the steps here
[mosquitto-tls — Configure SSL/TLS support for Mosquitto](https://eclipse.org/mosquitto/man/mosquitto-tls-7.php)

..and I can connect to Mosquitto securely using mosquitto_pub/sub etc...

What I haven't been able to do is manually create the keystore/truststores that JAVA needs from the Mosquitto steps... 
Or follow the ActiveMQ steps and then export the certs/keys for use by non-JAVA apps.

This is for MQTT on port 8883, but I'm sure that same challenges exist for anyone using SSL for sftp/https etc...

If anyone had a link to a good guide or could lists the steps to convert the ActiveMQ keystores/truststores for non-Java use, that would be really helpful.